# Is it possible to make a script/apk that will download another apk, install it and insert a specified text to the app form?

Tags: java, android

Is it possible, to write a code for android that will go to certain url, download an apk and then install it, open the newly installed app and lets say write something to it and press some buttons on it?

If so, then what are the options available to achieve this?(Aka automation app or to write an apk myself in android studio etc)

Answer (score 2):

You Can write Code that will Download an Apk but you can Not install it without The User Approval(excepted if the Device is Rooted),

You can launch install intent(system app install screen) once the Apk is downloaded with an Intent with the Action View and the data type set, also, since Android Oreo 8.0 The Apk which download the App will have to be Approved as install source by the user before launching the installation,

You can then launch the newly installed App and put extras in the intent launching this App, but in The app you have downloaded, it must handle the extras(in the Code of the downloaded App)